# What is the music in the DCS World Persian Gulf Map trailer?

Tags: game-music-identification, digital-combat-simulator-world

I was listening to the [*DCS World* Persian Gulf Map](https://www.digitalcombatsimulator.com/en/products/terrains/persiangulf_terrain/) trailer:

I loved the music, but couldn't find what song it was. What song is in this trailer?

Comment: It could be a track made just for the game, I tried to shazam it with no avail.

Comment: I wish it was on Spotify. They make tracks for the game. However, I loved it. So, I really hope that it is an actual song and not just a track made just for the game.